# Opengl failing to depth test properly

Tags: opengl, depth-testing, opengl-2.0

I'm was working on a really simple voxel like game, but for some reason OpenGL isn't depth testing properly.

Here's the relevant code:

```
//Render function:
void display() {
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    glLoadIdentity();

    glTranslatef(2.5, 2.5, -5.0);
    glColor3f(1.0, 0.5, 0.2);

    glBegin(GL_QUADS);
    int i, j, k;
    for (i=0; i<4; i++) {
        for (j=0; j<4; j++) {
            for (k=0; k<4; k++) {
                glPushMatrix();
                glTranslatef(-(float)i, -(float)j, -(float)k);
                glutSolidSphere(0.2, 32, 32);
                glPopMatrix();
            }
        }
    }
    glEnd();

    glutSwapBuffers();
}

//Set the initial state of OpenGL:
void initGL() {
    glEnable(GL_DEPTH);
    glEnable(GL_LIGHTING);
    glEnable(GL_LIGHT0);
    glEnable(GL_COLOR_MATERIAL);
    glEnable(GL_CULL_FACE);

    glClearColor(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
}
```

Made sure to include this is window initilization:

```
glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_DEPTH);
```

Here's a screencap:

[image: The result of rendering this code.]

I've tried disabling lighting features, but then it's difficult to tell what's on top of what anyway. I've tried disabling culling, nothing except the spheres are rendered inside out, which makes me think that maybe the problem is in the `glutSolidSphere` function and not my code. I'm using OpenGL 2.3.

Comment: Your `GL_VERSION` is `2.3`?  Really?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's called

```
glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
```

Not just GL_DEPTH